# Missing Authentication Request/Response POCOs in ServiceStack Clients

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack, servicestack-auth

After reading a lot about ServiceStack, I think it's such a beautiful work of art and I decided to use it for our upcoming Xamarin iOS App.

The problem currently is that after installing the ServiceStack.Client for Xamarin.iOS, I can't find the Request/Response DTOs (i.e POCOs) that are used for registration or authentication given that I have enabled the Authentication and Registration Plugins in the service host.

After digging into the source code, I found those Request/Response DTOs to reside in ServiceStack assembly which is a huge dependency and I don't think I can include it in our iOS App.

is there a way around that ? shouldn't these DTOs be shipped as well with the ServiceStack clients themselves under maybe ServiceStack.Client.Auth ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I guess I found them already available inside ServiceStack.Client .. what confused me is that I took some sample code from the C# client wiki and the DTOs were named differently and not available .. Thanks –